# Reload html page without refreshing page

Tags: html, ajax, reload, page-refresh

Hi,

I have an application where every server event is handled by Ajax.Our main goal is ,the total application should work with out refreshing page.But the page should be refreshed internally,means,the client should not feel like page is refreshed(The way, the content of tag is changed using Ajax).

So the thing is, page should be reloaded but not refreshed. Can we achieve this with Ajax?

OR

Is there any alternative do this?

Comment: This is more of a description of Ajax than a question. But yes you can do it. The user clicks a button, Javascript then asks a script (php) to do something. PHP returns the result as html & then javascript updates your page with the new HTML. The page is not refreshed, but javascript changes the html. This is basically what Ajax is.

Comment: Yeah I know that way..I think,my question is not clear to you...I want to reload the page but not refresh.In my case,input fields are binded to server variables dynamically.So input values are filled using Ajax event,and those should be reflected to page.It would be done if page is refreshed... got it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can also be done with Ajax, can u be more specific on what exactly you want to update on the form and the condition on witch the dynamic form will be changed on?

Comment: Ours is SAP BSP application,its just like JSP page.All the fileds of form are bonded to sap variables.So if variable is changed, then form fields should be changed automatically.SAP variables are changed on different actions using Ajax.So once ajax's onreadyStateChanged method execution is done, page should be reloaded that affects to form fileds to be refreshed with the changed SAP variable values...